# settimeout() not working; not setting time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a fencing game. When the up arrow is pressed, the fencer attacks. Here is my code:

```js
fenceRP += 100;
$(fenceR).html("<img src='fencerR2.png'/>"); // attack position
 $(fenceR).animate({ 'right': fenceRP +'px' }, 1, function () {
                     setTimeout(changeRBack, 1000);
                  });
// this is in a switch.
```

The problem is that however large the set timeout number is, it never stays in the fencer stays in the attack position for not enough time.

EDIT

After a bit of fiddling with my JS, i came across this solution:

```js
fenceRP += 100;
$(fenceR).html("<img src='fencerR2.png'/>");
$(fenceR).animate({ 'right': fenceRP + 'px' }, 1, function () {
                            setTimeout(function () { }, 1000);
                            setTimeout(changeRBack, 1000);
                        });
```

Comment: @Isaac what does this have to do with OP's question?

Comment: If I got your question right you could use JQuery's delay function as a more clean way of your solution. https://api.jquery.com/delay/